# Changing picture position in a modal (bootstrap 3)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an example modal here:

```
    <!-- Large Modal -->
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">funnycatnumberone</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8">
        <img src="cat1.JPG" class="img-responsive">
       </div>
       <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
           <p>brief description about my cat</p>
           <ul class="list-unstyled">
               <li>it has four legs</li>
               <li>also a tail</li>
               <li>likes boxes</li>
           </ul>
       </div>
       <br>
    </div> 
    <br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <img src="cat2.JPG" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <img src="cat3.JPG" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <img src="cat4.JPG" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
            <img src="cat5.JPG" class="img-responsive">
        </div>     
    </div>
</div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <a type="button" class="btn whateverclassimade" href="cutecatsmkay.php">check out some cats, yo</a>
        <a type="button" class="btn whateverclassimade" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When the modal opens, there is a title, a large picture (located on the left under the title), a brief description with some lines for added details, four pictures that are basically thumbnails directly under the main image, and some buttons to close the model or redirect the user to a different page.

Here's my question of sorts:
When a thumbnail (under the main image) is selected, I'd like that image to take the place of the larger image (aka take the main image stage). I appreciate the help!

Comment: can you share demo link?

Comment: you tried anything, use javascript; it shouldn't be a much trouble

Answer (score 0):

try this: 
`$("#thumbnail1").click(function(){ 
$("#main_image").attr("scr", "source of image"); 
});`
use id's corresponding to appropriate tag

Answer (score 0):

Simple Pure Javascript would be

```js
function imageSwap(catID) {
  document.getElementById("largeCat").src = document.getElementById(catID).src;
};
```

```html
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">funnycatnumberone</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8">
            <img id="largeCat" src="http://placekitten.com/g/500/600" class="img-responsive">
          </div>
          <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4">
            <p>brief description about my cat</p>
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
              <li>it has four legs</li>
              <li>also a tail</li>
              <li>likes boxes</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <br>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-2" onclick="imageSwap('smallCat1');">
            <img id="smallCat1" src="http://placekitten.com/g/500/300" class="img-responsive">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-2" onclick="imageSwap('smallCat2');">
            <img id="smallCat2" src="http://placekitten.com/g/500/400" class="img-responsive">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-2" onclick="imageSwap('smallCat3');">
            <img id="smallCat3" src="http://placekitten.com/g/500/500" class="img-responsive">
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-2" onclick="imageSwap('smallCat4');">
            <img id="smallCat4" src="http://placekitten.com/g/500/600" class="img-responsive">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <a type="button" class="btn whateverclassimade" href="cutecatsmkay.php">check out some cats, yo</a>
        <a type="button" class="btn whateverclassimade" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```